# Any Patches Available for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 14.04, shutdown

I have tested Ubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu 14.04 and in both cases I had issues with installing the latest nvidia driver from nvidia.com and also with being able to perform a scheduled shutdown using a GUI shutdown timer or from the command line/terminal with **sudo shutdown -h ....**. I also used software like Qshutdown and EasyShutdown but with no success so far.

I know there is a solution for installing upstream drivers directly from AMD's website [on this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) but there is nothing similar for Nvidia. I can't just use nvidia-173 Ubuntu driver because it comes with the wrong version for nvidia-settings, namely nvidia-settings version 304 or version 331. Can't adjust resolution, monitor frequency or use Power Mizer unless I try this [unusual solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451631/nvidia-173-driver-package-comes-with-the-wrong-and-useless-nvidia-settings-app). This goes for Ubuntu 12.04 as well as for Ubuntu 13.10 but at least with those releases I was able to install the latest video driver from Nvidia.com.

I noticed that nvidia-173 driver package present in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories can be activated only because it uses a patch to match Ubuntu 14.04 most famous kernel, and I was wondering if there are more patches like this one available out there to allow me to install the same software I used successfully in Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 13.10 including my video drivers from nvidia.com.

And I need to be able to schedule a complete shutdown (using the terminal emulator or some application like EasyShutdown or Qshutdown) without having to install kde shutdown utilities and a lot of other packages needed to run kde applications. Shutdown works only after installing these kde extra packages in Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to schedule a complete shutdown with `sudo shutdown -h <minutes integer>`.

Comment: I have Xubuntu 14.04 installed. Already tried that command. Something like sudo shutdown -h 15 or sudo shutdown -h 8:30. When it gets there, nothing happens. But I have just installed kde plasma desktop and some kde shutdown utilities and will give it another try next time I boot into the kde plasma desktop session. Maybe it will work. Amd Radeon drivers could work with [this solution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD). Found nothing similar for Nvidia so I keep using 'nvidia-173' drivers together with some tweaked 173.14.39 'nvidia-settings' I got from Debian.

Comment: **sudo shutdown -h 12:03** or similar works now both for the xfce session and the kde plasma desktop. I suppose the system needed those shutdown utilities that come with kde.